How do I add a setting selection for Rider to git so it is automatically set for anyone who opens the solution?
The solution I work on has a custom on-save reformat profile configured.
Everytime I check out a new instance of this repo, the selected reformat on save profile defaults to the Rider default setting.
What can I change so whenever someone pull the repo and opens the solution, the actions on save code reformat profile is already set to our custom one?

Store .editorconfig in source control? https://gist.github.com/neogeek/b4e4212fed7d0ad1c284b65207784f5e

Put .idea hidden subfolder of your project folder under version control.
